# fovis_ros and xtion (no rgb)

Tags: ros, rviz, xtion, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use fovis_ros with my xtion to build lately a 3d map using octomap , but when i start the launch file of openni2 and mono_deth_odometer of fovis package i have the following errors:

1)The camera say me that the image taken is uncalibrated.
2)Fovis_ros receive image and info from the respective topic , but the "synchronized tuples" are 0.
3)I cannot visualize in anyway the result from fovis_ros topic (features,pose,odoemtry).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213861/fovis_ros-and-xtion-(no-rgb)/) by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-16**:
This is the code of launch files [link text](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:5368)

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-10-27**:
If the answer pleases you, would you please mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Saracemo,

fovis needs grayscale rectified images. If color images are provided, they are converted to grayscale. Please use [the launchfile provided](https://github.com/srv/fovis/blob/indigo/fovis_ros/launch/fovis_hydro_openni.launch) in fovis_ros github source page and your openni launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-17**:
I will try !

**Comment by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on 2015-07-17**:
I had a question : Does fovis requires RGB image?? Because the xtion i had is unable. In this case , what kind of ros package i have to use to make visual odometry ?? THANKS

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-08-10**:
Hi Saracemo,
I'm trying to use fovis_ros with xtion this days. I use to use xtion with kinect and it could run.
I use openni2_launch and my system is ubuntu 64bit indigo.
Have you solve it?